# Should there be a colon before a title?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, semicolons

Which of the following sentences has been punctuated correctly:

> 1. This recommendation is based on a European guideline: Managing
>      Neuropathic Pain.
> 2. This recommendation is based on a European guideline, Managing
>      Neuropathic Pain.

Managing Neuropathic Pain is the title, and there are several European guidelines.

Comment: Both are fine, but the colon is better. You may wish to italicise the title of the guideline also.

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response.  Yes, the title will be italicised. I thought the second was wrong because there are several European guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

This is a style issue rather that a right-or-wrong issue.

You can use a colon, or italics (but both would be overkill), or single quotes, or even go all retro and underline the title. None of them are wrong, but they are different styles. If it is for publication, check their style guide. If it is not, either choose a style guide to follow or just do your own thing.

Here are some commonly used style guides.

**British English:**

[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a)

[The Economist](http://www.economist.com/styleguide/introduction)

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/design-principles/style-guide)

[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/news-style-guide/default)

[Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/topics/about-us/style-book/)

**US English**

[Chicago](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html)

[APA](http://www.apastyle.org)

[AAA](http://www.aaanet.org/publications/guidelines.cfm)

[National Geographic](http://stylemanual.ngs.org/home/A)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style)